# Flash embedded in HTML doesn't appear in Chrome but only in Safari

Tags: html, flash, interactive

I am coding interactive short story and  and embedded my Flash into my HTML page but it is not playing at all. It's just a black screen. The animation plays fine when using Safari though.
Help would be welcome ASAP.
This is the code I used to embed the swf file:

```
<div id="sleepingvideo">
    <object width="720" height="510">
        <param name="movie" value="SC_Flash.swf" />
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
        <param name="scale" value="noScale" />
        <param name="salign" value="lt" />
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="path=deuter" />
        <embed margin-height="100" width="600" height="400" src="survey.swf"
               flashvars="path=deuter" allowfullscreen="true"
               allowscriptaccess="always" name="player1" scale="noScale"
               salign="lt"></embed>
    </object>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use [SWFObject](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) for flash embedding. It works everywhere.